# apache poi writing only the last row

Tags: java, apache-poi

my application takes data from db and writes it to excel. i am using poi as java to excel converter
while writing  i am having a problem that only the last last row is getting written , can it be something realted to buffer, because a lot of data is being transported.

here is the code

```
for(int i=0; i<0;i<workorderlist.size;i++) {      
     //cargo start
     if(null!=workordervolist.get(i).getCargo()){
        String cargo = workordervolist.get(i).getCargo();
        cell = row1.createCell(15);
        cell.setCellStyle(nonEditable);
        cell.setCellValue(cargo);
        if(cargo.length()> colLenght[15]-2)
            colLenght[15] = cargo.length()+2;
      }
      //cargo end
}
```

Comment: Why does your for loop contain i<0; i<workorderlist.size - those are two conditions and would terminate your loop incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

As Ewald stated, your loop is not correct :

```
for(int i=0; i<0;i<workorderlist.size;i++)
```

I'm even surprised it compiles. The for structure is :

declaration of variable ; condition for stopping the loop ; incrementation.

You have two conditions, and no incrementation : most likely, you don't enter your loop, which you could see by using a debugger or putting a simple System.out.println("In the loop") after the for.

more than that, though,  where do you increment the row ? Where does row1 comes from ? You should have something like :

```
row1 = sheet.getRow(i);
```

So you'd need to post more code for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is not the full source code.
I just pasted a portion of it; I am sorry, I did not notice it is not syntactically correct.
I have fixed it.
The problem was that, in the `for` loop, I had used:

```
row = sheet.createRow(i);
row1= sheet.createRow(i+1);
```

So, every iteration cycle deleted the rows written before that.